# What is Catholic Church position regarding alcohol?

Tags: catholicism, sin, alcohol

I consider myself an Orthodox, and I'm from Eastern Europe (Not Russian, nor Ukrainian) and I discovered that we, Orthodox Christians, are very permissive regarding consuming alcohol. Of course, we believe that being a chronic alcoholic is a sin, however even if our official position regarding alcohol is "moderate drinking is fine", sometimes very religious people drink until they pass out (rarely, if you do this every day, then you are an alcoholic). We seem to believe that alcohol is a gift from God, rather than a demon (as other faiths believe). Of course, when someone abuses this gift, it becomes a demon, but we don't believe that drinking until strong drunkenness is bad once in a while.

What is the official position of the Catholic Church as a spiritual institution?

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1809/50259). I would also recommend reading the [Help Center](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help)'s sections on asking and answering questions.

Comment: The church is totally fine with alcohol in moderation. There are even some Trappist monks that produce and sell alcohol to provide for their monastery.

Comment: I've never heard of alcohol being referred to as a "demon" from any denomination, did you mean to say something else?

Comment: @Nacht I think to OP meant: "...alcohol is a gift from God, rather than [the gift of] a demon". Tolstoy wrote a play in which the Devil rebukes one of his staff for failing to corrupt a village of virtuous Russian peasants, and gives him a deadline to make them sin, or else. When the Boss returns a year later, he finds that Junior has invented vodka, and everyone is busily sinning. I think that the play ends with Junior being commended, and told to teach the rest of the staff.

Comment: @SimonCrase OP says "it becomes a demon" later, so I don't think that interpretation works

Comment: @Nacht maybe it's just an American thing, which expresses the "demonic" personal, societal and familial destruction wrought by drunkenness.  Rum was associated because rum was the most common spirit in the colonies.  https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/demon%20rum

Comment: Of course! How could I have forgotten that "The Demon Drink" was a popular slogan during the early decades of the 20th century - see [here](https://www.otago.ac.nz/library/pdf/hoc_fr_bulletins/33_bulletin.pdf) and [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/20112390). The US may have been the only Western country to adopt prohibition, but it was a [close call in NZ](https://nzhistory.govt.nz/prohibition-referendum-1919). One dictionary definition of demon is "evil spirit", and we refer to whisky, rum, etc as spirits, because it was "the spirit" of the wine (or whatever was distilled).

Comment: Related: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/50757/under-what-basis-does-the-catholic-church-condemn-the-use-of-drugs-while-permitt

Answer (score 10):

The Catechism has *alcohol* in its index.

> 2290. The virtue of temperance desposes us to *avoid every kind of excess:* the abuse of food, alcohol, tobacco or medicine. Those incur grave guilt who, by drunkenness or a love of speed, endanger their own and others' safety on the road, at sea or in the air.
>
> [Online at vatican.va](https://www.vatican.va/archive/ENG0015/__P80.HTM) [Quoted from the print edition, emphasis in the original]

Temperance is a virtue. Temperance does not mean abstinence. Alcohol has been around since the time of Noah and has long been enjoyed; but one should avoid following Noah’s example. [[Genesis 9:21](https://www.catholicstudybible.org/WebBibleTAL/WebPlayer.aspx?bbNum=01009&bVerse=21&F=cbBookPickResult)]

Comment: Additionally, *drunkenness* is sinful. Note Ephesians 5:18, but also, it should be self-evident that drinking to the point that you are no longer in control is evil.

Comment: But what does moderation mean? Shoud you not drink over the "mild dizziness" stage(2-3 glasses of wine, or half a glass of strong spirit, or a couple of beers), or you can get drunk and pass out very rarely, like Noah. I was raised in an orthodox family. My parents drank all kinds of alcoholic bevreges, but never got drunk. When I was 18, and I could legally purchase alcohol, I bought a rum bottle and drank it all, alone at home. I fell on my face in the mud in the garden and I passed out. I threw up in sleep all day. It was not a mistake, I was very courious what it means to be heavily drunk.

Comment: Since then I never got drunk again. Now I see a lot of alcoholic man beating their wives, children and I'm not sure, because in a lot of Bible passages, the wine seems to be praised as a healer of the soul and flesh, but when people starts to do really bad things under influence. And I know that they passed the sinful limit long ago, but they started with a beer, a glass of wine and became dependent, so they must be driven this way by Satan in a way, but how can something that the Bible says its good like wine, be used as a weapon against God by Satan, by destroying human souls

Comment: "How can something good be used against God?" is a whole nother question (and could probably be asked).

Comment: @Bogdan The world isn't quite so black-and-white. Many things can be "good" in moderation, but shouldn't be taken in excess (like sugar or pain pills). Different people respond differently to alcohol, and there could be a variety of contributing factors that leads to someone becoming an alcoholic abuser. Many people drink regularly without going down that path. Moderation means whatever is very unlikely to lead to you harming others or yourself (although some would say moderation is never getting drunk). It's less a question of *how often*, because it just takes 1 mistake to ruin or end lives.

Comment: @Bogdan The theoretical side of Catholicism is strongly influenced by [St. Thomas Aquinas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Aquinas), and he in turn was influenced by Aristotle (who he calls "the Philosopher", as if there was no other). Aristotle and Aquinas both stressed [moderation in all things](https://www.oxfordreference.com/display/10.1093/oi/authority.20110810105420435;jsessionid=24408A8C5E9D9EFCE7EBD39720DDB744): here is [one of the many things Aquinas wrote about moderation](https://www.newadvent.org/summa/3141.htm).

Comment: @Bogdan "... in a lot of Bible passages, the wine seems to be praised as a healer of the soul and flesh". I see no contradiction between this and instances of alcohol abuse: you can overdose on Vitamin D, or on aspirin; abusing antibiotics can lead to resistant strains of bugs. I've never heard of vitamins, aspirins, or antibiotics being labelled "demons".

Comment: The way I *personally* understand the Church's teaching on that matter: (a) You may never drink heavily enough to lose control over your behavior (much less get completely wasted) and (b) you may not habitually drink heavily enough to seriously risk getting yourself addicted. Aside from this, you decide in your conscience what 'temperance' means for you, so that you avoid serious risks of serious harm.

Comment: @Bogdan "*but they started with a beer, a glass of wine and became dependent, so they must be driven this way by Satan in a way*" - IIRC science says that all habitual use of alcohol, even in small quantities carries some risk of getting addicted (however relatively small risk, if you stay within 'safe' limits) - therefore addiction is often not a drinker's guilt, unless of course we consider drinking-more-often-than-only-occasionally a wrongdoing.

Answer (score 1):

There is an entertaining article [here](https://www.catholic.com/magazine/print-edition/the-communion-of-saints-and-the-consumption-of-alcohol-0). I can't resist quoting a few paragraphs.

> One need only cite the Eucharist as a *sed contra* to the alleged iniquity of alcohol. Consider the following statement: "For the Blessed Sacrament, in which he gives us not only his grace but his very self, our Lord Jesus Christ, the Son of God, chose as its matter a Group 1 carcinogen of untrammeled malevolence."  Does that not sound a bit strange?

> Nor should we waffle on the fact that wine is by its very nature a form of alcohol. St. Thomas Aquinas goes so far as to suggest that wine was chosen for the Eucharist not despite its alcoholic content but in part because of it. Aquinas reasons that just as bread is good for the body (gluten detractors notwithstanding), wine is good for the soul insofar as it “cheers the heart of man” (Summa Theologiae III.74.1). And wine produces that cheer, we hasten to add, by the C2H5OH contained therein.

> Even within the New Testament we find "dry" saints like John the Baptist, who abstained in anticipation of the Messiah, and “wet” saints like Paul, who recommended wine for one’s health (see 1 Tim. 5:23).

Comment: Very interesting the differentiation between the saints. Another thing, back to Old Testament, and to Noah who planted a vineyard, made wine and got very drunk. The thing is that the Bible doesn't blame Noah for doing this, doesn't say that he sinned or did a bad thing by doing this. They blame more the son who saw him naked and drunk.